What circuit could I use to detect that there is no ground connection?
I'm trying to design an Electric Vehicle Supply Equipment (EVSE) and want to add a circuit capable of detecting no ground connection. I've seen that some EVSEs can detect this, so my question is: What circuit could I use for this purpose?

I am attaching an image where there is an EVSE with all the correct electrical connections, but it does not have the grounding connection. This is the type of error I am referring to."


You mean no GND connection of the EVSE to power grid or no GND connection to the car or both?

@StefanWyss,  I have already edited the question where I explain the type of error I want to detect.

Assuming that the left side of the diagram has connections not shown back to the AC mains from the building power.  The Neutral will be connected to the Protective Earth (PE) Ground back at the facility entrance box, and for the PE to be effective, there must be potential energy between the phase lines and the correctly connected PE (i.e. the phases have to be referenced to Earth somewhere back on supply side).  So measuring continuity between Neutral and PE or measuring a high AC potential between any Line and PE at any load device (EVSE or otherwise) should be sufficient to verify that PE connection is present.

I have used some type-2 AC chargers and some of them can detect when there is no physical ground connection. When the ground connection is removed, the equipment stops and alerts that there is no ground connection. I still don't understand how it can detect that the ground connection is not present.

@WalterPH  A device connected to the AC mains (with Neutral and PE wires) could internally compare the voltage sensed from Line to Neutral against voltage sensed from Line to PE.  If Line to PE voltage is much lower, then indicate fault that PE is open.  If they are the same voltage, then PE is connected and no fault.
